# Unique count of comma separated cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say I have a cell containing the following : `[A, B, C, B, A]`.  How would I be able to get the unique values along with their counts?  ex. `A = 2`, `B = 2`, `C = 1`

Comment: Use text to columns and then do a count of the resulting cells?

Answer (score 0):

Select the cell containing the data and run this short VBA macro:

```
Sub WhatsInIt()
    Dim s As String, arr
    Dim c As Collection, a
    Dim i As Long, msg As String

    Set c = New Collection
    msg = ""
    s = ActiveCell.Text
    s = Mid(s, 2, Len(s) - 2)

    arr = Split(s, ",")
    On Error Resume Next
        For Each a In arr
            c.Add a, CStr(a)
        Next a
    On Error GoTo 0

    For i = 1 To c.Count
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & c.Item(i) & vbTab & aCount(c.Item(i), arr)
    Next i

    MsgBox msg
End Sub


Public Function aCount(st As String, ary As Variant) As Long
    Dim ar
    aCount = 0
    For Each ar In ary
        If ar = st Then aCount = aCount + 1
    Next ar
End Function
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

This version puts the result in cells:

```
Sub WhatsInIt2()
    Dim s As String, arr
    Dim c As Collection, a
    Dim i As Long, msg As String

    Set c = New Collection
    msg = ""
    s = ActiveCell.Text
    s = Mid(s, 2, Len(s) - 2)

    arr = Split(s, ",")
    On Error Resume Next
        For Each a In arr
            c.Add a, CStr(a)
        Next a
    On Error GoTo 0

    With ActiveCell
        For i = 1 To c.Count
            .Offset(i - 1, 1).Value = c.Item(i)
            .Offset(i - 1, 2).Value = aCount(c.Item(i), arr)
        Next i
    End With

End Sub

Public Function aCount(st As String, ary As Variant) As Long
    Dim ar
    aCount = 0
    For Each ar In ary
        If ar = st Then aCount = aCount + 1
    Next ar
End Function
```

*(the aCount() function is unchanged)*

Comment: Thank you! That worked, but is there a way to get the values to show up in an adjacent cell or have a column for each unique value along with the count?  Mainly to get the values on the worksheet.

Comment: @RonDoe  See my **EDIT#1**